# Embedding \soulomit in a macro

Tags: macros, soul

In the MWE below, the code:

```
\MyUl{abd \soulomit{\MyLink{www.google.com}{The Google}} ghi}
```

works exactly as desired:

[image]

However, when I attempt to wrap this in a macro, and use

```
\MyUl{abd \SoulOmitMyLink{www.google.com}{The Google} ghi}
```

I get:

> Argument of \SoulOmitMyLink  has an extra }.

### Question:

What changes are required to `\SoulOmitMyLink` to get this to work?

### Notes:

- The following is not an option for my current use case:

  ```
  \MyUl{abd} \MyLink{www.google.com}{The Google}  \MyUl{ghi}
  ```

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{soul}
\setulcolor{red}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\NewDocumentCommand{\MyUl}{%
    s%   #1 = starred variant
    O{}% #2 = options, if any
    m%   #3 = mandatory param
}{%
    \ul{#3}%
}%

\NewDocumentCommand{\MyLink}{%
    s%   #1 = starred variant  (unused as of yet)
    O{}% #2 = options, if any  (unused as of yet)
    m%   #3 = link text
    m%   #4 = link target
}{%
    \href{#3}{#4}%
}%

\NewDocumentCommand{\SoulOmitMyLink}{%
    s%   #1 = starred variant  (unused as of yet)
    O{}% #2 = options, if any  (unused as of yet)
    m%   #3 = link text
    m%   #4 = link target
}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        \soulomit{\MyLink*[#2]{#3}{#4}}%
    }{%
        \soulomit{\MyLink[#2]{#3}{#4}}%
    }%
}%


\begin{document}
\MyUl{abd \soulomit{\MyLink{www.google.com}{The Google}} ghi}

%\MyUl{abd \SoulOmitMyLink{www.google.com}{The Google} ghi}% I want this
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As explained by Joseph Wright in his [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120582/16967), package `soul` does not support arbitrary commands. The following example shows, how `soul` can be extended to support `\SoulOmitMyLink`. It hooks into the code `\SOUL@docmd` that processes the data of `\soulregister`. The code is inserted for the case that the second argument of `\soulregister` is `8`. Then the command in the first argument is also tested, whether it is `\SoulOmitMyLink` and the special treatment for this case is added.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{soul}
\setulcolor{red}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\NewDocumentCommand{\MyUl}{%
    s%   #1 = starred variant
    O{}% #2 = options, if any
    m%   #3 = mandatory param
}{%
    \ul{#3}%
}%

\NewDocumentCommand{\MyLink}{%
    s%   #1 = starred variant  (unused as of yet)
    O{}% #2 = options, if any  (unused as of yet)
    m%   #3 = link text 
    m%   #4 = link target
}{%
    \href{#3}{#4}%
}%

\NewDocumentCommand{\SoulOmitMyLink}{%
    s%   #1 = starred variant  (unused as of yet) 
    O{}% #2 = options, if any  (unused as of yet)
    m%   #3 = link text
    m%   #4 = link target
}{%  
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        \soulomit{\MyLink*[#2]{#3}{#4}}%
    }{%
        \soulomit{\MyLink[#2]{#3}{#4}}%
    }%
}%

%%% Patch begin %%%
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\SOUL@docmd{\else\ifx7}{%
  \ifx\SoulOmitMyLink#2%
    \SOUL@doword
    \let\SOUL@@\@undefined
    \NewDocumentCommand{\SOUL@@}{sO{}mm}{%
      \IfBooleanTF{##1}{%
        \soulomit{\SoulOmitMyLink*[##2]{##3}{##4}}%
      }{%
        \soulomit{\SoulOmitMyLink[##2]{##3}{##4}}%
      }%
      \SOUL@scan
    }%
  \fi
  \else\ifx7%
}{%
  \soulregister{\SoulOmitMyLink}{8}%
}{}
\makeatother
%%% Patch end %%%

\begin{document}
\MyUl{abd \soulomit{\MyLink{www.google.com}{The Google}} ghi}

\MyUl{abd \SoulOmitMyLink{www.google.com}{The Google} ghi}% I want this
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

(I have used option `colorlinks` for `hyperref` to show in a clearer way that you do not want to have a line for the link.)

### Update

- According to Peter Grill's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120580/embedding-soulomit-in-a-macro/120588#comment268881_120588) the macro `\SoulOmitMyLink` is no longer needed.
- The redefinition of `\SOUL@@` that scans the arguments for `\MyLink` do not need to check the arguments and call `\MyLink`. It can directly pass the arguments to `\MyLink␣code`, the internal macro that `xparse` defines, if a macro is defined via `\NewDocumentCommand`.

The updated and shorter example file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{soul}
\setulcolor{red}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\NewDocumentCommand{\MyUl}{%
    s%   #1 = starred variant
    O{}% #2 = options, if any
    m%   #3 = mandatory param
}{%
    \ul{#3}%
}%

\NewDocumentCommand{\MyLink}{%
    s%   #1 = starred variant  (unused as of yet)
    O{}% #2 = options, if any  (unused as of yet)
    m%   #3 = link text
    m%   #4 = link target
}{%
    \href{#3}{#4}%
}%

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\SOUL@docmd{\else\ifx7}{%
  \ifx\MyLink#2%
    \SOUL@doword
    \let\SOUL@@\@undefined
    \NewDocumentCommand{\SOUL@@}{sO{}mm}{%
      \csname MyLink code\endcsname{##1}{##2}{##3}{##4}%
      \SOUL@scan
    }%
  \fi
  \else\ifx7%
}{%
  \soulregister{\MyLink}{8}%
}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tracingmacros=1
\MyUl{abd \soulomit{\MyLink{www.google.com}{The Google}} ghi}

\MyUl{abd \MyLink{www.google.com}{The Google} ghi}% I want this
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great. I just noticed that I can remove the call to `\soulomit` from the `\SoulOmitMyLink` macro.  Hence, I can just eliminate `\SoulOmitMyLink` totally and simply use `\MyLink`.

Comment: I don't understand how `##1` and `##2` work here?  Perhaps there is some magic about the first parameter being a `*`, but how is the mandatory `{##2}` (mandatory since it is surrounded with curly braces) interpreted as the optional first parameter (which was expected to be within a square bracket)?  I only saw that you had updated the solution as I am having trouble using two _consecutive_ (without any text in between) uses of `\MyLink` within `\MyUl`.  Your code here works great for that case, so I don't know what is going on with my actual use case so was wondering how this all worked.

Comment: Ok, found my problem: my arg specs were not matching, so after fixing that now things work for the _consecutive_ issue outlined above (your code does not have this problem). But, for me using `{##1}{##2}{##3}{##4}` did _not_ work. But, using `\IfBooleanTF{##1}` as a switch and then passing either `*[##2][##3]{##4}` or `[##2][##3]{##4}` depending on the switch did work.

Answer (score 5):

The `soul` package works by doing a token-by-token decomposition of the input, which can be bypassed by `\soulomit` if it appears in the text to be decomposed. In your example, `\soulomit` does *not* appear in the input that `soul` sees. What happens is that `soul` extracts `\SoulOmitMyLink` and tries to use it with no argument, which is where the error comes in. Bottom line: you *can't* hide `\soulomit` inside another macro, as `soul` looks for that as a literal and not for it being used (it doesn't actually *do* anything).